# I am unable to fetch all user data from backend API using Redux Toolkit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am developing an ecommerce store on MERN Stack using Redux Toolkit. I have implemented Login Functionality and it is working fine. Now I want to fetch all user/customer data and update the Redux Store but I am unable to do it. Backend API is working fine, I have tested it on Postman. I am new to Redux Toolkit. Kindly review the code and point out the mistake.
Thanks

This is customer slice:

```
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import customerService from "./customerService";

export const getUsers = createAsyncThunk(
  "customer/get-customers",
  async (thunkAPI) => {
    try {
      return await customerService.getUsers();
    } catch (error) {
      return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(error);
    }
  }
);
const initialState = {
  customer: [],
  isError: false,
  isLoading: false,
  isSuccess: false,
  message: "",
};
export const customerSlice = createSlice({
  name: "users",
  initialState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(getUsers.pending, (state) => {
        state.isLoading = true;
      })
      .addCase(getUsers.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.isError = false;
        state.isSuccess = true;
        state.customer = action.payload;
      })
      .addCase(getUsers.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.isError = true;
        state.isSuccess = false;
        state.message = action.error;
      });
  },
});
export default customerSlice.reducer;
```

This is customer service code:

```
import axios from "axios";
import { base_url } from "../../utils/base_url"

const getUsers = async () => {
  const response = await axios.get(`${base_url}user/allusers`);
  console.log(response.data);
  return response.data;
};

const customerService = {
  getUsers,
};

export default customerService;
```

This is Redux store code :

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import authReducer from '../features/auth/authSlice'
import customerReducer from '../features/customer/customerSlice'


export const store=configureStore({
    reducer:{auth:authReducer,customers:customerReducer}
})
```

This is Customer store page where I want to display the data. I have not used useSelector because it is showing state empty in Redux Dev tool:

```
import React from 'react'
import {useDispatch,useSelector} from 'react-redux'
import { Table } from 'antd';
import { useEffect } from 'react'
import { getUsers } from '../features/customer/customerSlice';

const columns = [
  {
    title: 'No.',
    dataIndex: 'key',
  },
  {
    title: 'Name',
    dataIndex: 'name',
  },
  {
    title: 'Product',
    dataIndex: 'product',
  },
  {
    title: 'Status',
    dataIndex: 'status',
  },
];
const data1 = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 46; i++) {
  data1.push({
    key: i,
    name: `Hanzla Zahid ${i}`,
    product: `Laptop ${i}`,
    status: `Pending ${i}`,
  })
}

const Customer = () => {
  const dispatch=useDispatch()
  useEffect(()=>{
    dispatch(getUsers())
  },[])
  return (
    <div>
    <h3 className='mb-4 title'>Customers</h3>
    <div><Table columns={columns} dataSource={data1} /></div>
</div>
  )
}

export default Customer
```

This is Backend api code:

```
GetAllUsers=asyncHandler(async(req,res)=>{
    try{
        const data=await User.find()
        res.json(data)
    }catch(err){
        console.log(err)
        console.log("Users Data Not Fetched")
    }
})
```

Comment: What does your `console.log(response.data);` logs from the `getUsers` fn?

Comment: It shows nothing. I tried fetching data directly through axios and useEffect hook and it fetched the results, It means the backend is working fine.